# How to traverse this JSON structure

Tags: jquery, json

The below is from Yahoo Finance API and I am looking to extract the 64.730003 from `"price": "64.730003"`

I am trying this by using the below, but what am I doing wrong?  I am guessing its something to do with data.list.resources.resource.fields.price  as I can never seem to figure out traversing JSON format.

```
$.getJSON("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/BZM15.NYM/quote?format=json")
        .done(function (data) {
        $("#result").html("$"+ data.list.resources.resource.fields.price);
  })
```

JSON:

```
{
    "list": {
        "meta": {
            "type": "resource-list",
            "start": 0,
            "count": 1
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "resource": {
                    "classname": "Quote",
                    "fields": {
                        "name": "Brent Crude Oil Last Day Future",
                        "price": "64.730003",
                        "symbol": "BZM15.NYM",
                        "ts": "1429823631",
                        "type": "future",
                        "utctime": "2015-04-23T21:13:51+0000",
                        "volume": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resources is a list, notice `[]`

```
data.list.resources[0].resource.fields.price
```

But I am more used to traverse in dictionary format

```
data['list']['resources'][0]['resource']['fields']['price']
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to convert this to an object using JSON.parse(jsonString); Then you could use:

```
obj.list.meta....
```

...etc